# When does the quantum start?

Tags: operating-system, scheduler, context-switch

When talking about the scheduler in operating systems. Everytime a process is been executed the operating system gives it a quantum (the maximum time it can be executed without calling de scheduler). My doubt is, when the quantum expires, the next quantum is automatically started, or it waits for the context switch to be completely done to start?

Comment: 'Everytime a process is been executed the operating system gives it a quantum' no.  If there are no more ready threads than cores, there is no need for any 'quantum', (an inappropriate term for a unit that is far from discrete).